# PHP Remove Text Between [ and ] Parentheses

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to remove text included between [ and ] parentheses (and parentheses, too).

For example:

Hello, [how are you]

Must become:

Hello,

And, a string like:

hello, [how][are] you

must become:

hello, you

There is a regula expression to do that?

Comment: What about nesting? Does it need to handle strings like `[foo[bar]baz]`?

Comment: And the extra spaces, do you want them removed?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to remove everything between `[]` with the `preg_replace` function.

```
$a = 'hello, [how][are] you';

echo preg_replace('#\s*\[.+\]\s*#U', ' ', $a); // hello, you
```

The regex catches every spaces before and after and replace it with a single space.

Be careful, `[` and `]` are reserved characters in regex, you need to escape them with `\`. If you want to keep the possibility to write `[]` in your string (without anything between), you can transform the `.*` in `.+`.

Comment: What happens with nested square brackets `Hello, [how [are] you]?` My guess is that it would result in `Hello,  you]?`. (not verified) If such constructs are guaranteed not to occur, Maxime's solution should work.

Comment: @hek2mgl Fixed by truncating spaces before and after (and insert a single space in replacement)

Comment: Add Ungreedy modifier, satisfied? :)

Comment: @hek2mgl In fact, I explicitly add a space between I found two elements seperated by `[]` should be concatenated after. But it's my personal interpretation after :)

Comment: why not just using this `preg_replace('~\[.*?\]\s?~', '', $str)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if you want to deal with nested brackets and extra horizontal whitespaces:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~\h*\[(?:[^][]+|(?R))*+]\h*~', ' ', $txt);
```

or with an unrolled loop:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~\h*\[[^][]*+(?:(?R)[^][]*)*+]\h*~', ' ', $txt);
```

Comment: Oh god, why so complex? Which cases do you manage to have such a long regex?

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
print preg_replace('/\[[^\[\]]*\]/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `\[.*?\](?![^\[\]]*\])` to handle nesting as well [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xS6hA3)